# nut and nut-monitor won't connect to tripp-lite ups using Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ups

I have a tripp-lite AVR700U ups but **nut** and **nut-monitor** doesn't see it. Does anyone have a good write up that works?  Everything I find is several years old and doesn't work with my setup?  I'm trying to disable the power outage beeping sound.  I'm using ubuntu 18.04 64bit desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of commands that worked for me.

(Some more Tips can be found at https://linux-tips.com/t/disabling-ups-beep-under-linux/592)

```
sudo apt-get install nut
sudo apt-get install nut-monitor
```

(stop if started)

```
sudo upsdrvctl stop
```

Open / edit the following files as root
**Example:
sudo nano /etc/nut/nut.conf**

1- Changes to make to file **nut.conf** -add the lines below:

```
MODE=standalone
```

2- Changes to make to file **ups.conf** file -add the lines below:

```
[tripplite]
driver = usbhid-ups
port = auto
productid=3024
desc = "Tripp Lite AVR700U"
```

3- Changes to make to file **upsd.conf**  -add the lines below:

```
LISTEN 127.0.0.1 3493
LISTEN ::1 3493

[tripplite]
driver = usbhid-ups
port = auto
```

4- Restart nut

```
sudo service nut-server restart
```

5- Changes to make to file **/etc/nut/upsd.users** -add the lines below:

Example:

```
#admin is the username
[admin]
password = "test1234"
actions = SET
instcmds = ALL
```

5- Reload upsd with the new users config:

```
sudo upsd -c reload
```

6- Start driver

```
sudo upsdrvctl start
```

If you get an error saying **Can't claim USB device [09ae:3024]: could not detach kernel driver from interface 0: Operation not permitted**

You can use **lsusb** to find out the bus and device number for the Tripplite UPS

Then change permission of the device

```
chmod 0666 /dev/bus/usb/[bus number]/[device number]
Chmod 0666 (chmod a+rwx,u-x,g-x,o-x,ug-s,-t) sets permissions so that, (U)ser / owner can read, can write and can't execute. (G)roup can read, can write and can't execute. (O)thers can read, can write and can't execute.
```

Example:
Type:

```
lsusb
```

Look for the **Tripp Lite** line

**Bus 003 Device 012: ID 09ae:3024 Tripp Lite**
*(Note if you unplug your usb connection and plug it back in this may change)*

```
sudo chmod 0666 /dev/bus/usb/003/012
```

7- Start Driver

```
sudo upsdrvctl start
```

8- You can query the list of the commands which will be supported by your ups device with the upscmd

```
upscmd -l tripplite
```

9- To see the status of beeper

```
upsc tripplite ups.beeper.status
```

10- To disable beeper

```
upscmd tripplite beeper.disable

Username: admin
Password:  test1234
```

11- To check it's been disabled

```
upsc tripplite ups.beeper.status
```

Note: You can use a gui after the setup is complete called **nut-monitor** to see all the options / settings in real-time. https://networkupstools.org/projects.html

Comment: Thank you for this -- I needed step six.  For my particular needs and distribution, I actually put the "nut" user into the "usb" group, then all is well.  No permissions changed, because the device is already 660 and group "usb"!